# Which roles are required to "Create Work Item" in Azure DevOps from Application Insights

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights

We connected our Application Insights resources in Azure to our Azure DevOps. And those of us with Contributor roles are able to successfully create work items in ADOP from App Insights. We would like to give our Product Management team the same ability, but don't want to give them Contributor roles. Which roles are required for them to create work items from App Insights directly in ADOP?

Comment: Hi Justin, any update for this issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: Yes. It solved the problem. I marked it as an answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you please click the `check mark` button underneath the vote buttons of my answer below(instead of the button under your question) to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442)? The `check mark` button is located at the position of my answer, the marked answer would look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63790022/10910450). Thx~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [Select a Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control#select-a-role). Since `Reader` role can only view but not change anything, you need at least **Application Insights Component contributor** role to modify and create work items.

Comment: Is there any role less broad? While we want Product Management to be able to create Bugs in ADOP, we don't want them to have the ability to edit anything inside App Insights.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The document above has listed the related roles/permissions about Application Insights. It's obvious that you can't limit the Product Management's access to Reader if they should have the ability to create WIT from failures. There's no role level between Contributor and Reader, you have to pick one of them, it's by design that readers should only view and contributors should edit Application Insights resources.

Comment: There's no less broad role which is higher than reader, lower than contributor... Please check the document above for more details.