# Naming resulting ZIP archive in Azure Pipelines build?

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines

Still trying to get a full grasp on the Azure Pipelines and what I can do with those...

I've managed to finally get my little .NET Core command line utility built with Azure Pipelines - now trying to publish it as a build artifact.

With this YAML, I can build and package the tool:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: False
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'MyTool_LatestBuild'
```

But in the published build artifacts, I only get a file `a.zip` - is there any way I can influence the name of that ZIP archive?? I'd really love to have something like `MyTool_2020_Sep_08.zip` or `MyTool_v1.5.7.zip` something.... but how can I do that?? Can't seem to find anything very useful anywhere on the interwebs ... any inputs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1.Agree with **Vernou**. You can customize the name by specifying the folder name that contains your binaries. So we need to modify the `--output` argument of `dotnet publish` step and `PathtoPublish` argument of `PublishBuildArtifacts` step.

2.But to get Date time, you can use [Build.BuildNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) which is predefined variables.

My working sample:

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: False
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyTool_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/MyTool_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    ArtifactName: 'MyTool_LatestBuild'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

More details about using BuildNumber to get date, you can check [Configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

**The result:**

[image]

We can control the format via modifying how we define the `Build.BuildNumber`(In Yaml, it's `name`). If we define `name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)`, then the output zip would be `MyTool_20200908.zip`.

Comment: @marc_s Glad to know it makes some help :)

Comment: I've had to add `modifyOutputPath: false` to the input list to stop the pipeline from adding the project name (from the .csproj) to the end of the path specified with `--output`.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: Loking at vernou's answer - i was wrong, i'll leave this here because some may prefer to have different steps and we all love copying from SO.

The Task you're using does not contain that power, but you can (like i have) opt to zip it yourself instead:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: |
      **/*Client.csproj
      **/*WorkerService.csproj
      **/*Server.csproj
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.StagingDirectory)/ci-build --no-build --self-contained -r $(runtime)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

# Archive the /staging/ci-build folder to /staging/RemoteData.<BuildNumber>
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)/ci-build'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

# Publish the zipfile as artifact
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    ArtifactName: 'RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

This has the added benefit of being able to more closely manage your jobs:

[image]

As you can see each step is laid out separately here.

Comment: For now, @Vernou 's answer doesn't work, since I keep getting an error .... I'll try your approach next - thanks ¨

Comment: Yes - thanks - your approach works fine - but I agree - the solution by @Vernou with a little help from Lance Li is more elegant and less involved. But I also agree: other times it might be more useful to make archiving and publishing separate steps - so I'll also keep your solution in my repository of great SO answers - thanks !

Comment: Well our pipeline is larger than this excerpt and we ran into performance issues where some steps took a long time. I first had everything together and dotnetpublish did most of the heavy lifting, but then i split out everything so i could pinpoint and debug better. Also there's charts about the pipelines performance which just display better with different steps. Great you got a working solution though.

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet publish` task copy file in the output and zip this folder. You can output to folder with a suffix like :

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(solution)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: False
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app_v1.5.7'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'MyTool_LatestBuild'
```

You can define a build number and replace the suffix with :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

```
...
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: False
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    zipAfterPublish: True
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, trying this, I keep getting: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(101,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "D:\a\1\a\MyTool_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)\". The directory name is invalid. : 'D:\a\1\a\MyTool_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)\' [D:\a\1\s\MyTool.csproj]"

Comment: Thanks - combined with the additional inputs by Lance Li, this solution you've proposed now works nicely.

Comment: Exact, $(date) isn't a pipeline variable, just a keyword to define the build number. I have corrected my answer. For more detail on the build number, see Lance LI answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get a file `a.zip` is because the publish folder is named `a`.

For Windows put this after the dotnet publish step to see it:

```
- script: |
    dir $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /s
  displayName: 'List Contents of Output Directory'
```

This happens when you have selected "Place solution and project in the same directory" during project creation.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines#inputs):

> **modifyOutputPath - Add project's folder name to publish path**
> Optional. Use when command = publish. Default value: true.
>
> If this input is set to true, folders created by the publish command
> will have the project file name prefixed to their folder names when
> the output path is specified explicitly in arguments. This is useful
> if you want to publish multiple projects to the same folder.

This doesn't work as expected if there is no project's folder name, so my suggestion is to set it to false and add another subfolder to `--output`.